# How to recognize this sequence pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What's the pattern for the following sequence $-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1 \cdots$
>   And what is its series?
>
> I tried $(-1)^{n^3+1}$ and many things with no successful results.

Thanks

Comment: @lab bharracharjee for n=3 ==> 2

Comment: $(-1)^{(n+2)(n+3)/2}$

Answer (score 2):

lets see this $$ \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor$$
put n=1,2,3,...
$$a_{n}=\left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor=1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,...\\$$
so
$$b_{n}=(-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor}\\$$put n=1,2,3,4,5...
$$(-1)^1,(-1)^1,(-1)^2,(-1)^2,(-1)^3,(-1)^3,(-1)^4,(-1)^4,...\\$$ $$-1,-1,+1,+1,-1,-1,+1,+1,...$$